# Unsharp PNG logo on website

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, png, html

I've an issue I've been struggelig with a while now. I've made a logo with Illustrator CC 2015 for my new website. The issue is that on most Windows computers, the logo looks unsharp, while on Macs it looks perfect. I suspected first it has something to do with DPI, though I'm not sure as it more seems like some kind of scaling issue maybe in Windows?

You can check it out at: http://preview.apexsolutions.no/beta/

On Mac the logo looks sharp and everything, while on Windows it's more unsharp almost smudged. I've played around with the Export settings of Illustrator, it's currently exported as Type Optimized and Interlaced. Interlaced seemed to help a bit, but not enough. Exported on my Mac instead of Windows did no difference.

I thought maybe the thickness of the font was the issue, but I tested a bit thicker version and it still gives the same problem. I even tried just do a simple HTML IMG, and same issue occurs, so it doesn't seem to be something in the website code either.

So now I'm stuck and not sure what I should check or do in order to solve this issue. Any help would be greatly appericiated! :)

Comment: I think it'd be good to include the image in the *question itself* so that people can see it when the problem is fixed and also prevent an unnecessary click to your site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logo has a size of 1159x175px and is downscaled to 298.017x45. (firefox on linux)

I suggest you either use a file that has the exact dimensions (298x45) so the browser will not have to downscale it or you use svg which is a vector graphics format and can be scaled up or down without loss of quality.

Comment: Alright, I tried to make it exact size, that helped a bit indeed, though it does not make the logo responsive anymore for retina screens and so on. I ended up with convering whole thing into SVG, and it looks.. better. I couldn't get the svg to link the font properly, so I just made whole thing paths before to SVG, not the best choice, but it works I suppose. You can see the result on the same link.